# Нужна ли запятая? И однородны ли слова?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

***Но я заметил, что идём мы ровно, не петляя(,) и видим...***

Касательно однородности: *однородны ли обстоятельства **ровно** и **не петляя**?* 
И нужна ли запятая?
Благодарю заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая ставится, если второе обстоятельство поясняет (или уточняет) первое:

**Но я заметил, что идём мы ровно, не петляя, и видим...**

В данном случае, в предложении осложненной  структуры  при наличии однородных сказуемых,  обособление желательно.

Но **пояснительные значения близки к однородным**, если подбирается подходящий по смыслу синоним, и **обстоятельства  "ровно, не петляя" могут входить в однородный ряд,** например: Идти по  лесу ровно, не петляя, как по ниточке  было сложно.